# DOM paser setExpandEntityReferences(false) prducing both entity reference and expanded text node

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I want to parse a XML document and keep it's representation as close to source as possible, in particular I want to get ENTITY_REFERENCE nodes. But insted I get ENTITY_REFERENCE node followed by a TEXT_NODE which represents expansion of the entity reference.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.DOMImplementationLS;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSOutput;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSSerializer;
import org.xml.sax.EntityResolver;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        final String xml = new String(
                    "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + 
                    "<!DOCTYPE simple SYSTEM \"simple.dtd\" [" + 
                    "<!ENTITY a \"abhijeet\">" + 
                    "]>" +
                    "<simple> &a;   </simple>");

        builder.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {

            @Override
            public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) throws SAXException, IOException {
                return new InputSource(new StringReader(""));
            }
        });
        Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

        final DOMImplementationLS domImplementationLS = (DOMImplementationLS) builder.getDOMImplementation();
        LSSerializer LSSerializer = domImplementationLS.createLSSerializer();
        LSOutput LSOutput = domImplementationLS.createLSOutput();
        LSOutput.setCharacterStream(new PrintWriter(System.out));
        LSSerializer.write(document, LSOutput);
    }

}
```

If you like run the code here: http://ideone.com/Rldi2S

Result on hotspot:
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_15-b03)
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)

Is the same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE simple SYSTEM "simple.dtd" [<!ENTITY a 'abhijeet'>
]>
<simple> &a;abhijeet   </simple>
```

Where "&a;" is entity reference node followed by it's expansion "abhijeet" text node.

What I expected is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE simple SYSTEM "simple.dtd" [<!ENTITY a 'abhijeet'>
]>
<simple> &a;   </simple>
```

**Is it my lack of knowledge, bug in my code or is the parser broken?**

Answer (score 0):

It really seems to be a bug in the parser:
https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8206132

I have had the same issue using JDK 11. According to the ticket above, the bug seems to be fixed in JDK 13 upwards. I can confirm it is fixed in JDK 15.

Using JDK 15 and setting `factory.setExpandEntityReferences(false)` I get separate `Text` and `EntityReference` nodes in the DOM tree. I get the original text without expanded entities calling `getNodeValue()` on the `Text` node and the original entity name (without `&` and `;`) of the `EntityReference` calling `getNodeName()` on the respective node.